# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600,000

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I get following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600,000
```

When executing following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

service = Service(r'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

I am running the code on Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) with Selenium 4.1.3, Chrome 98.0.4758.106 and same Chrome Driver Version.

Sometimes the script runs without any errors and sometimes I get this time out.

I hope that someone can help me out.
Thank you!

Comment: add this option `options .addArguments("--disable-gpu");` and see if that helps

Comment: @cruisepandey `--disable-gpu` was a windows specific argument which is no longer needed now, where as OP is on non-windows os.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium: gpu stands for graphic processing or something else here?

Comment: Right, graphic thing but was required only for windows systems